# how to switch from 2D to 3D view in UWP hololens app

Tags: uwp, hololens

I am making one UWP application in which I have to show first 2D view when application is launched in hololens . Then from that 2D view I have to switch 3D holographic app. Basically I wnt to launch a hologram from 2D app.

I followed this link https://mtaulty.com/2016/10/25/windows-10-uwp-hololens-and-switching-2d3d-views/ . I am able to switch views but the problem is I want to switch from 2D view to 3D (holographic) view and by using this link first comes 3D hologram then your 2D app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn'it what you are looking for (except droids ;)) : http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2016/06/29/hololens-launch-a-3d-holograms-app-from-a-2d-xaml-app-and-going-back-to-it-uwp/

Regards